# Multiple requests to Internet Server simultaneously from same browser

Tags: language-agnostic

I sometimes wonder what happens when you submit a form multiple times and the internet server is processing the previous request? Is there any problems that can be caused in any special condition?

**Edit** Any problems at the client end? for example when webserver send two responses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each form submit will be processed separately, possibly many in parallel. Depending on your application this may or may not screw up data server-side. The server-side script may stop processing if the HTTP connection is dropped though (upon clicking "Submit" again, the first request is canceled and a new request send).

To avoid problems with multiple submissions, you can for example send a unique ID with the form that will be checked on the server and can only be used once. Or you can set an "already-processing" flag in the user's session. Or you can work with job-queues and check if a job for the user already exists. The specifics would depend on your application.

Re: *"Any problems at the client end? for example when webserver send two responses?"*

Whenever your browser sends a request, it establishes a connection to the server on which it will wait for a response. New request, new connection. When you click a submit button a second time, the first connection is dropped and a new one established (that's also the point where the server usually stops processing the old request). That's why you can load multiple pages of the same site in a browser at the same time, it won't get confused which response is meant to go into which tab.

Answer (score 0):

On e-commerce sites, people have accidentally purchased multiple times because they were impatient and kept hitting the submit button before waiting for (the sometimes slow) response.

It's a good idea to disable the submit button after it had been pressed in this type of application.

Comment: Disabling the submit button is not a terribly reliable solution, but it is one more thing you can do.

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution that doesn't require careful synchronization or coordination between threads is to reconcile actions that occurred too close together after the fact. Did a user click on two ads half a second apart? Unlikely they actually visited the first site. Did a user submit two orders for the same bag of goods a minute apart? Probably a mistake.

As long as you have a way to identify identical events or even "from the same person" too close together, you can use this technique.